# Is it possible to remove the "batch" dimension of input after training?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

When I train the image classification model, the input shape is `(None, Height, Width, Channels)`.

After train, I need to deploy it by `tf-serving`, and I still need to post a tensor with shape `(None, Height, Width, Channels)` to the production server.

Is it possible make it accepts `(Height, Width, Channels)` without reshape the single image input?